# Topology - Open Neighborhood Systems

Tags: general-topology

I'm still a little confused on the concept of open neighborhood systems after attempting this problem:

Let **R** be the set of real numbers. Assume **t** to be the topology induced on **R** by the absolute value metric and **t'** to be the topology defined on **R** by means of the open neighborhood system given below:

For each x contained in **R**, let **t'** be the set of all half-open intervals having x as a left-hand endpoint; that is: **Nx** = { [x, a) | a is contained in **R** , x < a }.

a) Prove that the collection of **Nx** described actually satisfies the definition of the open neighborhood system.

b) Prove that every **t** -open set is also **t'** -open.

c) Prove that there are **t'** -open sets which are not **t** -open.

d) Prove that **t'** is not the discrete topology.

Please, let me know if you can help--thank you!

Comment: I guess that the notion of "open neighborhood system" is similar to that of "basis". Is your notion standard? What is the context of your problem?

Comment: I answered what I've done in the questions below. But, I am stuck on (d)..

Comment: For (d), I think I need to show that t' fails a property of the discrete topology. I was considering showing that a set in t' is not closed and opened (which is a requirement of the discrete topology).

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the notion of "open neighborhood system" is similar to that of "basis". And I will follow the notations in Munkres's Topology (2nd edition).

> **Basis:** If $X$ is a set, a *basis* for a topology on $X$ is a collection $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of $X$ (called *basis elements*) such that
>   (1) For each $x \in X$, there is at least one basis element $B$ contains $x$.
>   (2) If $x$ belongs to the intersection of two basis elements $B_1$ and $B_2$, then there is a basis element $B_3$ containing $x$ such that $B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$.

Using this notion of *basis*, the first topology $\tau$ you mentioned is the one generated by the basis consisting of all the $(a,b)$ intervals of real line $\mathbb{R}$, and the second one $\tau'$ is the one generated by the basis consisting of all half-open intervals of the form $[a,b) = \{ x \mid a \le x < b \}$. Conventionally, $\tau$ is called the **standard topology** on the real line, denoted simply by $\mathbb{R}$ and $\tau'$ is called the **lower limit topology**, denoted by $\mathbb{R}_{l}$.

Your problems (*in particular, the first three problems*) are actually guiding you to compare these two topological spaces. It turns out that $\mathbb{R}_{l}$ is *finer* than $\mathbb{R}$. You can check the details in Munkres's Topology (Lemma 13.4 of Section 13 "Basis for a Topology").

**For (d):** As you have commented, it is sufficient to give a subset which is not *clopen* (clopen for both closed and open). From the first three parts, we have known that $\mathbb{R}_{l}$ is finer than $\mathbb{R}$, which means that every open (or closed) set in $\mathbb{R}$ is also open in $\mathbb{R}_{l}$. Consider the one-point subset $\{ 0 \}$. It is closed in $\mathbb{R}_{l}$, for it is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. However, it is not open in $\mathbb{R}_{l}$, because *there exists no* basis element of the form $[a,b)$ which contains the point $0$ and is also contained in $\{ 0 \}$.

Comment: That makes total sense. I want to prove c and d by first showing that tau is contained in tau'. Can you explain how I would show that tau is a subset of tau'?

Comment: I think I got it. How about this:

Comment: When approaching (b) and (c), note that τ is contained in τ’. To show this, assume ϰ and ϰ' are open neighborhood systems for τ and τ’, respectively. We will show that, for each real x and N∈ϰ_x, there is N'∈ϰ_x' such that N^'  ∁ N.
Proof:
Assume X to be any τ-open set and x is contained in X. Then, there is N∈ϰ_x such that x∈N ∁ X. Now if there is N'∈ϰ_x' such that x∈N' ∁ N, then x∈N' ∁ X, i.e. X is also τ’-open. Thus, τ is a subset of τ’. Conversely, if τ is a subset of τ’, then N∈τ' since N∈τ. Therefore, there is N'∈ϰ_x' such that N^' ∁ N. ℘

Comment: For (d), I think I need to show that t' fails a property of the discrete topology. I was considering showing that a set in t' is not closed and opened (which is a requirement of the discrete topology). Would this work? I am not sure how to get started.

Comment: @SKA The subset $\{ 0 \}$ is closed but not open in $\mathbb{R}_{l}$. I have edited my last answer to include the details.